# How to avoid loading iframe twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

when I try to refresh an `iframe` using the below code.
My Iframe loads twice. resetting the message on div that I set after the refresh.
I am using below code for this.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeid');   
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

Comment: Maybe, your code that calls the iframe refresh is called twice. Please give a better example.

Comment: The refresh is called only once. I am using websphere portal server and Spring MVC implementation for portlets.The render method is actually rendered twice whenever a page is refreshed or loaded. Seems like something with render method of portlets.